# как при :hover на родительский элемент сделать display: block у дочернего

Tags: sass, hover, бэм

привет, подскажите плиз

как при :hover на родительский элемент сделать display: block у дочернего, когда у дочернего по умолчанию стоит display: none.

использую sass и бэм

```
@mixin make-container-max-widths {
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.nav {
   display: block;
   &__horisontalLine {
      &--top {
         margin-bottom: 0;
         margin-top: 0;
         border-top: 1px solid #e1ddd8;
         padding-bottom: 2px;
      }
      &--bottom {
         padding-top: 2px;
         margin-bottom: 0;
         margin-top: 0px;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #e1ddd8;
         border-top: 0 solid #e1ddd8;
      }
   }
   &__container {
      @include make-container-max-widths;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 18px;
   }


&__menu {
      display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
      list-style: none;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding-left: 0;
      max-width: 1150px;
      margin: 0;
   }
   &__menuItem {
      position: relative;
   }
   &__menuItemLink {

      &:hover {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #1c285b;
         border-top: 4px solid #1c285b;
         padding-top: 24px;
      }
      &:active {
         border-top: 4px solid #1c285b;
         padding-top: 24px;
      }
   }
   &__subMenu {
      list-style: none;
            display: none;
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 0;
      background-color: #1c285b;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
   }
   &__subMenuItemLink {

      &:hover {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #c4ab2e;
      }
   }
   &__subMenuImg {
      display: none;
      &:hover {
         display: block;
      }
   }
}
```

Фиддл: https://jsfiddle.net/4p5f06v9/

задача у меня такая: при ховере на Wedding должен появится дропдаун с под меню, а когда ховеришь по пунктам в подменю то должны появиться картинки.

не понимаю как при ховере включить дочерний елемент.

хотел реализовать без вложенностей типа: .parant .child:hover {...}

спасибо!

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь то .parent:hover+.child{display:block;}

Comment: вы правы, спасибо!